# Delete 3 selected records in jqgrid alert box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

When I select 3 rows from jqgrid for deletion at that time I want the pop up should display as "Delete Selected 3 Records" but correctly its displaying "Delete Selected Records".

Following is my code which I written for delete function.
Currently it is displaying an error as "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

```
 var ids= $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
   var count=ids.length;

    var myDeleteOptions = {
        msg: "Delete selected"+count+"records?",
        afterComplete: function(response, id){
            //alert(response.responseText);
            var msg=response.responseText;
            var n =msg.search("Deleted");
            if(n>=0)
                $(".inner").html("<div class='alert alert-success fade in'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>X</button><i class='fa-fw fa fa-thumbs-up'></i>  "+msg+" </div>");
            else
                $(".inner").html("<div class='alert alert-danger fade in'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>X</button><i class='fa-fw fa fa-thumbs-down'></i>  "+msg+" </div>");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't posted more full JavaScript code which you use. `delGridRow` method of jqGrid have `msg` option, but you need to set the option **dynamically directly before** calling of `delGridRow` method. It's the first problem.

The second problem in your code: the clear error. You use `selrow` option to detect the *ids* of all deleted rows in multiselect mode. Instead of that you should use `selarrrow` option which is the arrays of ids of selected rows. Alternatively you cal use get comma-separated list of deleting ids from `#DelData` hidden filed of the dialog.

So I would recommend you to use `beforeShowForm` callback instead of using  `msg` option. Inside of the callback you can assign new text to `.delmsg`

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var ids = $form.find("#DelData>td").text().split(",");
    if (ids.length > 1) {
        $form.find(".delmsg").text("Delete selected " + ids.length + " records?")
    } else {
        $form.find(".delmsg").text("Delete selected record?")
    }
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomDeleteMessage.htm) which display the dialog like

[image]

or like

[image]

depend on the number of deleting rows.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I made it work by using following code:
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
            var selr=jQuery('#jqgrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')
           
            $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Delete "+ selr.length+ " selected courses?");
            
        },

Comment: @ChiruAdi: It's one option which I wrote you. I used `$form.find("#DelData>td").text().split(",")` instead of `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow")` only to have the code which work in the same way whether multiselect is enabled or not. Moreover there are some scenarios where `delGridRow` can be called **without previous selection of deleted rows**. In the case the usage of `$form.find("#DelData>td").text().split(",")` will still work, but `selarrrow` will be not set.